# Specify a jenkins home on the slave from the master

Tags: linux, jenkins, redhat, master-slave

I'm trying to connect a jenkins slave with SSH and I have the following error :

```
[SSH] Remote file system root  does not exist. Will try to create it...
java.io.IOException: Could not copy slave.jar into '' on slave
```

I have very limited permissions on the computer, which must be the source of the error.
Therefore I would like to :

- Change the repository where the slave.jar is copied (move it to `/myRepository`)
- Change the installation repository of jenkins to /myRepository/jenkins

Can it be done through the master ? I tried setting `JENKINS_HOME` to `/myRepository/jenkins` on the slave configuraiton, but it didn't work.

Thanks

Comment: What are exactly "limited permissions on the computer"? Can you login to it from console?

Comment: I mean that I can only RWX in my home directory `/home/user123`. I ended up solving my problem by specifying this repertory in the _distant work directory_ field of my slave configuration